# I want to get value before and after colon with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is the example of my string:

```
or id:bBkeed 
or name:Michael
or surname:Kronenberg
```

Here is the array of different values with same type and I need to create an array of values before colon and after colon.

```
const afterDOT = splitedValue[index].substring(splitedValue[index].indexOf(':') + 1);
const beforeDOT = splitedValue[index].substring(0, splitedValue[index].indexOf(':'));
afterDOTS.push(afterDOT);
beforeDOTS.push(beforeDOT);
```

I need do the same but with regex can somebody help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: plz format your example string .. can't distrinct

Comment: By ‘*dots*’ do you mean colon?

Comment: var x = "id:bKess" or var array = ['id:34', 'surname:kronenberg', 'name:Michael']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try that:

```
([^:\s]+):([^:\s]+)
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/L0T2GJ/4)

```js
const regex = /([^:\s]+):([^:\s]+)/g;
const str = `id:bBkeed or name:Michael or surname:Kronenberg`;
let m;

var before=[];
var after=[];

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    before.push(m[1]);
    after.push(m[2]);
}
console.log(before);
console.log(after);
```

Comment: Your regex does not match empty strings, you may remove `if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }`

Comment: I am note quite sure about the empty space thing whether the op needs it or not .. that part was  a bit clumsy in the question ... So i guessed it that way ... just look into the sample input ;) ... apart removed the thing that you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [.match(regex)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

```js
var str = "abc:xyz";
var first = str.match(/(.*):/g).pop().replace(":","");
var last = str.match(/:(.*)/g).pop().replace(":","");

console.log("String : " + str, "\nfirst : " + first, "\nlast : " + last);
```

---

You can easily extend this for your case. See below :

```js
var string = "abc:xyz id:234 surname:kronenberg";

string.split(" ").forEach(function(str) {
  var first = str.match(/(.*):/g).pop().replace(":", "");
  var last = str.match(/:(.*)/g).pop().replace(":", "");
  console.log("first:" + first, "last:" + last);
});
```

Comment: in my case i can got only one value in my string like as "abc:xyx"
but i am expect "abc:xyz id:234 surname:kronenberg"

Comment: You can easily extend this for your case. I have shown you the solution. And if you want your problem specific solution, see the update